# How to capture sample output of a never-ending process in bash?

Tags: bash, process, output

I am using a tool that you can only interrupt using `Ctrl-C` (or `kill`). This is monitoring a certain component and reporting some info every few seconds. The tool does not have support for specifying a limit how many times check the component before exit. So it will run forever until it is stopped.

How can I capture a sample of this output into a variable for further processing? I also have to stop this monitoring tool and continue processing.

Comment: Do you want to stop the tool once it has generated a certain amount of output, or should the tool continue after you have the output you want to work on, and separately you will later stop it?

Answer (score 1):

You could output the data to a file and just run `tail` on that file that file to get current output. You can clear the file when it gets too big. If you want a more specific answer you'll need to provide more detail.
For instance if your process is called `printJunk`, you can start it as

```
./printJunk >>afile.txt
```

then  *at any time or times while `./printJunk` is running*, you can run the command below to get the most recent 10 lines into a variable:

```
someVariable=$(tail -n 10 afile.txt)
```

Viewing the output of the file and assigning it to a variable won't have any effect on the runtime of `./printJunk`.

When afile.txt gets too large, do echo >afile.txt to empty it. Again, `./printJunk` won't care that this happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe your tool to another program, and *that* program exits, your tool will receive the `SIGPIPE` signal the next time it tries to write to the (now closed) pipe and exit.

Here's an example that captures the first 10 lines of output from your tool.

```
sample=$(your-tool | head -10)
```